# Implications of using Serializable and Snapshot isolation concurrently

Tags: sql-server, transactions, snapshot, serializable

Are there any issues using SNAPSHOT isolation to read data consistently for viewing without locking, blocking or dirty/phantom reads, while a separate process is processing continuous incoming data in serializable transactions?

We need readers (guaranteed read-only: web data sync, real-time monitoring views, etc) to be able to read consistent data, without being blocked, or blocking the updates. We were using SNAPSHOT for everything, but had too many consistency failures so switched the updating process to SERIALIZABLE.

I've read about but am not totally clear as to the impacts of using different isolation levels concurrently. I've seen the [lock compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396.aspx), and read various info. It seems ok, but I'd really appreciate some wise guidance from people with practical experience about any major pitfalls.

Are there any issues using Snapshot isolation for the readers while SERIALIZABLE transactions are writing? Are there circumstances it will block a SERIALIZABLE transaction? Is there a benefit to using SNAPSHOT vs READ COMMITTED (with READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON)?

Thanks, any assistance greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reads performed under SNAPSHOT isolation level read any modified data from the version store. As such they are affected *only* by writes. Writes behave *identically* under all isolation levels. Therefore SNAPSHOT reads behave the same way no matter the isolation level of the concurent transactions.

READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON makes READ COMMITTED act as SNAPSHOT. In effect, it is SNAPSHOT: the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT was provided as a quick way to port applications to SNAPSHOT w/o code changes. So everything said on the first paragraph applies.

Comment: Thanks! Is there ever a circumstance when reads under SNAPSHOT isolation could cause a SERIALIZABLE transaction to block? (at first I thought of using the NOLOCK hint, but read some commentary that there are risks so SNAPSHOT would be better)

Comment: If the SNAPSHOT transaction does a write then it can block any transaction, including SERIALIZABLE ones. If the SNAPSHOT transaction does stricly reads, then it will not block any other transaction on *locks*. There are other types of resource contention (ie. block on something else not locks) but those are extreme cases like memory exhaustion and not ordinary operations. In any case, SNAPSHOT reads is by far your best option.